# How to write a batch file which processes sql statements

Tags: batch-file

how to write a batch script which will take a file as an input, then it will perform a sql query on that file and give a file as an output.

input will be a textfile which has 4 query in it. Now a batch file is to be written which will take 1 query at a time and execute it and output will be stored in a file. So there will be 4 seperate output file for 4 query

Comment: be specific, is this file in CSV format? Also please rephrase your question title - it's way too generic.

Comment: you have asked another question which has far more detail and is to the point. I suggest you simply close this one as too vague and concentrate on your other one which is a lot better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895725/batch-file-which-will-take-a-text-file-as-an-input

Comment: I added your reply to the answers also to the question above, and rephrased the title a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which sql server you are using, in this example I will use firebird. If you use a different sql server, you have to use the correct sql commandline tool and syntax. firebird uses isql.exe.

Asuming I have the following text file "input.sql" containing 4 sql commands:

```
select * from CUSTOMER;
select * from DEPARTMENT;
select * from EMPLOYEE;
select * from SALES;
```

Then this batchfile will execute each command using isql.exe, and creates a seperate output file for each command:

```
@echo off

set sql_exe="C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\isql.exe"
set sql_options=-u sysdba -p masterkey
set sql_db="C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\examples\empbuild\EMPLOYEE.FDB"
set count=1

for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.sql) do (
  echo %%a > temp.sql
  call :processtemp_sql
)
goto :eof


:processtemp_sql
%sql_exe% %sql_options% -i temp.sql -o output%count%.txt %sql_db%
set /A count=%count%+1
goto :eof


:eof
```

at the end output1.txt..output4.txt are created. Each file contains the output of one sql command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't often perform SQL queries on a normal file, it generally requires a DBMS (database management system) at the other end for interpreting the SQL and extracting the relevant data.

Writing a batch file is relatively easy, be it a UNIX shell like `bash` or the Windows `cmd.exe`.

But, if you're thinking about implementing a full blown SQL query language that operates on text files (or any non-database file, really), that's probably going to take more then one question on Stack Overflow :-)

Perhaps you could flesh out your question with a little more detail, given that we may have misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: The task is to automate the process. So have to write a batch script to parse this file , The input will be the attached file and What I all finally need is only the sql query in a single line and output should be in file. The each input file will have an 4 Sql query. So each sql query need to be in new line.

Comment: @sudeep: so what you're asking for is an SQL interpreter and extraction engine to be written, which will handle the file you _haven't_ attached and write the extracted data to a file? If that's the case, I don't think you fully understand the complexity of what you're proposing.

Comment: input will be a textfile which has 4 query in it. Now a batch file is to be written which will take 1 query at a time and execute it and output will be stored in a file. So there will be 4 seperate output file for 4 query

Comment: so what to  write in the batch file so that it will take a text file as an input?

Comment: @sudeep, see my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895725/batch-file-which-will-take-a-text-file-as-an-input

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Microsoft Log Parser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en). It allows you to execute SQL queries on a a number of file types, including logs, CSV and XML files.

Comment: input will be a textfile which has 4 query in it. Now a batch file is to be written which will take 1 query at a time and execute it and output will be stored in a file. So there will be 4 seperate output file for 4 query