# Batch file which will take a text file as an input

Tags: batch-file

What command will make a batch file receive input from a text( .txt) file?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a transcript showing a batch file that will do what you want:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Pax> type qq.cmd
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
    echo.LINE^> %%a
)
endlocal

C:\Pax> type qq.txt
hello
goodbye

C:\Pax> qq qq.txt
LINE> hello
LINE> goodbye
```

The `for` statement reads the lines one at a time into the variable `%%a` (`delims=` is needed otherwise spaces are used for breaks and you'll only get the first word on each line rather than the whole line.

`%1` is the argument passed into the batch file, `qq.txt` in this case.

Everything else is just support stuff that I use to get the best `cmd.exe` environment set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the names as parameters and capture them.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file) for details.